# final letter "y", following a vowel, yet representing another syllable

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonetics, phonology

Is there a word in English, in which the final letter "y", while following a vowel, would represent another syllable?

For example, in the words "worry", "story", "sassy" the final letter "y" stands for one syllable (wo-rry, sto-ry, sa-ssy), but it doesn't follow a vowel.

On the other hand, in such words like "boy", "say", "key" the final letter "y" follows a vowel ("o", "a", "e"), but it doesn't stand for another syllable.

Perhaps, the word "buoy" is the answer to my question - but only if the right way of splitting it into syllables is "buo-y". If the right way is "bu-oy", then it's not.

Comment: It's _buoy_ actually, and it is pronounced as a single syllable (like _boy_).

Comment: @KateBunting - I learned recently that many Americans say 'boo-ee' for 'buoy', giving it two syllables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cakey](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cakey), chocolatey, blokey, wakey-wakey (timey-wimey if you're a Doctor Who fan).

I suspect they might have started off with a hyphen y, and then over time the hyphen was dropped. You can use that construction to make a few non-standard jokey (there's another one!) adjectives.

> I'm having a bake-y weekend.
> The lake was very mosquito-y.

"Bake-y" isn't a real word, but most native speakers would understand exactly what you were meaning.

Buoy doesn't work if you're British.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any words where `y` becomes its own syllable. Perhaps this is because it usually changes the last vowel, or combines with the last consonant to form a syllable.